# Trouble retrieving data with JDBC in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc

I am pretty new to Java so I'm working on a project to develop my knowledge with databases and Java.

I have figured out how to add queries into the database but now I'm getting errors when trying to print them out.

Assume I already have everything that's necessary imported in such as the scanner and sql statements

Here is my connection class which is named MainClass:

```
public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testTable";
    String username = "placeholder";
    String password = "placeholder";
    Class.forName(driver);
    Connection conn = Driver Manager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    return conn;
}
```

Now in a different class if the user types !lookup and a word I want the definition of that word to be retrieved from the table whose name is dictionary and columns are word, definition:

```
String userSearch = user_input.next();
String[] userSearchSplit = userSearch.split(" ", 3);

if (userSearchSplit[0].equals("!lookup")) {

    try {
        conn = MainClass.getConnection();
        String query = "select definition from dictionary where word=" + userSearchSplit[1];
        ResultSet result = pstmt.executeQuery(query);

        while (result.next()) {

            String definition = result.getString("definition");
            System.out.println(definition);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            pstmt.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

At the end of all this when I try to look up a word I put in the table before running I get:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Where have your created Object of **PreparedStatement**?

Comment: there are tons of other errors in your Code !! Try Debugging ASAP

Comment: I don't have any errors in my actual code. This is a recreation where some things had to be modified but this is the part I'm having the most trouble with. Any errors you see are most likely errors made when I typed it in the question.

Comment: By Seeing only the above code snippet I doubt you haven't initialized `pstmt` reference variable !! which is likey to cause `Null Pointer Exception`

Comment: Could you explain your first comment? I read a couple of tutorials but the only bit they had about prepared statments was ResultSet result = pstmt.executeQuery(query);

Comment: copy paste your code -- use system properties for the sensitive parts -- and include a complete stacktrace along with your exception, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your user_input is null?

I am assuming your code:

```
ResultSet result = pstmt.executeQuery(query);
```

as

```
Statement pstmt = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet result = pstmt.executeQuery(query);
```

Or it could be that you have not initialized the pstmt properly

Comment: I've switched my statement to this
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT output FROM commands WHERE name=" + splitMessage[1]);

ResultSet result = pstmt.executeQuery();

But now I get an null pointer exception at finally try block where it says pstmt.close();

Comment: Please paste your code block for the request. @Mr.Smithyyy